# Chart.js line chart is cut off at the top?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

For some reasone all graphs are cut off at the highest value.
How can i fix this? I can't use a fixed y-axis

[image: Line Chart cut off at the top]

Comment: Do you have fiddle?

Comment: What are you using to create the graphs? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Please create a snippet (explained here https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to show your code.

Comment: @nourdin did you ever get a fix for this? I'm running into it too.

Answer (score 26):

**Edit/Update:** As mentioned in the comments, the 5px value can more accurately be just half of whatever your line width value is, I belive default is 2px so in that case you would just want padding: { top: 1 }

There a layout.padding attribute you can set either in options or global. I had this same problem and set

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      top: 5
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

worked fine for me to not cut off the line
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-layout-configuration

Comment: Yeah, this worked for me. I was having cut off problems with the polar area chart and padding the canvas did nothing. padding the layout as you state here fixed the problem. Good catch!

Comment: This doesn't help, it just pushes the whole graph down by 5px.

Comment: @RocketR I guess to be more clear, The default line width is 2(px) but it places the line in the center of that, so if your chart goes to 100%, 1 px of that will be cut off above the canvas. So maybe a more accurate solution is 

top = half of your borderWidth value;

Comment: I tried different values, it just pushes everything down, including the legend. The best workaround I managed to find is adjusting the scale `max` in the `afterDataLimits` callback. Cutting off only happens when the graph exactly touches the top grid line, so if you add just 1px at the top, it works fine.

Comment: In my case padding does not help. Lines still cut and the white space just gets larger.

Answer (score 21):

You can try `clip:false` option, worked for me.

Example:

```
options: {
    clip: false,
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
    }
 }
```

Comment: You save my life!

Answer (score 5):

I used hardcode, just wide draw area at top and bottom. This code based on original Chart.canvasHelpers.clipArea.

```
const WIDE_CLIP = {top: 2, bottom: 4};

Chart.canvasHelpers.clipArea = function(ctx, clipArea) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
      clipArea.left,
      clipArea.top - WIDE_CLIP.top,
      clipArea.right - clipArea.left,
      clipArea.bottom - clipArea.top + WIDE_CLIP.bottom
    );
    ctx.clip();
};
```

Comment: This is the exact problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found this while making line graphs that had the legend displayed at the top. The only work around I found was to move the legend to the bottom

```
options: {
    legend: {
       position: 'bottom',
    },
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/3j0pag31/)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this Chart.js bug, too.

A very recent fix is shown [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4971/commits/6501391e3072eba14961209aaaa88fad335a5b62).
You'd have to manually edit your Chart.js file `src/controllers/controller.line.js`
(For Angular 2, this file path will be located inside directory `node_modules/chart.js/`.)

Or just wait for the next Chart.js release which will most likely contain the fix.

An alternative workaround is described in comment 1 of this bug ticket:
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4202

Answer (score 0):

The `options.layout.padding.top` solution didn't work for me (just added padding AFTER the line cut), so I extracted the **high/low** values from my data and used the `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` config params like this:

```
var suggestedMin = {MIN};
var suggestedMax = {MAX};

options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: suggestedMin - 1,
                suggestedMax: suggestedMax + 1,
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution might be the most optimal one but I have one problem: `Uncaught ReferenceError: suggestedMin is not defined`.

Comment: @Emir It says in the error `suggestedMin is not defined`. You need to define it `var suggestedMin = VALUE_YOU_CALCULATED;` and the same thing for `suggestedMax `.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't see that. I thought you were increasing `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` from the chart's options. By the way, is that possible (to only increase the `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` values, like for example: `suggestedMin++`)?

Comment: @Emir Didn't try that but IMO it should work. Careful thought if you gonna use the variable more than once, as it will be incremented/decremented each time.

Answer (score 0):

I had my data values stored in array. So I set my max and min values like this:

```
var _array = [1,3,2];
var suggestedMax = Math.max.apply(Math,_array); // 3
var suggestedMin = Math.min.apply(Math,_array); // 1
```

And than you can set

```
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    suggestedMin: suggestedMin - 1,
                    suggestedMax: suggestedMax + 1,
                }
            }]
        }

    }
```

And it works, thank you.

Comment: should the code at the top read:
`var suggestedMin = Math.min.apply(Math,_array); // 1
var suggestedMax = Math.max.apply(Math,_array); // 3`

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the Chart.js library. Just update it and you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm currently using v3.5.1 and still seeing this issue.

Comment: Using 4.4.0 and still seeing this issue.