# Chart.js migration from v2 to v3 lost tick label at y-axis max, with log scale

Tags: chart.js

I've finally managed to slog through the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html), but a couple things are still broken.

For this question: How can I force a labeled tick line for the max on the y-axis (in this case “16.1”). Looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72220949/176841) from an unrelated question, it seems like this is only an issue with log scale graphs (the whole reason I'm trying to migrate to v3 is a different bug in log scale graphs in v2...)

v2 (good):

[image]

v3 (bad):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed with the upcomming release of chart.js V4, the tick calculation has undergone some refinement in this pr: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/9166

Result:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {

      },
      y: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        min: 2,
        max: 19
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/master/chart.umd.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```